# How to instruct grunt HTMLmin to ignore PHP markup

Tags: javascript, php, html, gruntjs

I am using [HTMLmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) in my grunt.js workflow to minify my HTML.

I have a few files that also include PHP markup. For example:

```
<a href="<?php echo //code ?>">link</a>
```

HTMLmin doesn't parse this correctly, and instead throws an exception error:

```
Warning: [filename]
Parse Error: <a href="<?php echo //code ?>">link</a>
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Is there anyway to instruct HTMLmin to ignore PHP markup? I've looked through the docs but don't see any obvious answer.

Comment: Which version of grunt-contrib-htmlmin are you using? I tested your example using grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.1.3 and it does work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The world of modern JS doesn't take into account running in a subdir or templates that go through any kind of server side manipulation.  The trick would be to inject the PHP *after* grunt minifies with some kind of data-* attribute.  I haven't developed a solution I'm fully happy with.  But, you can try some grunt regex tasks to do something like this

```
<a data-phphref="<?= $templatePrefix;?>" data-phpclass="<?= $activeLink;?>" href="/foo/">Foo</a>
```

after custom grunt task

```
<a href="<?= $templatePrefix;?>/foo/" class="<?= $activeLink;?>">Foo</a>
```

Or you can do full DOM manipulation, which would probably be the better long term choice.

#### Update

I guess there's a 3rd option, and that would be to do token replacement to make regex easier.  You can watch your source template files in a directory like ui-src/  When a change happens, run a simple search/replace for tokens

```
<a href="{{templatePrefix}}/foo/">Foo</a>
```

Output to a template directory that PHP is configured to use.  This should allow you to minify like

```
<!-- build:js {{templatePrefix}}scripts/plugins.js -->
<script type="application/javascript" src={{templatePrefix}}components/bootstrap/js/affix.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

With a grunt task like:

```
      "string-replace": { 
        template: { 
            files: { "./": "<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html.php"},
            options: { 
              replacements:[ { 
                  pattern: /{{templatePrefix}}/,
                  replacement: "<?= $templatePrefix;?>"
              }
            ]
            }
        },
```

A bonus would be to put the PHP code snippets into a JS config file so your PHP code isn't littered throughout your Gruntfile.js

### 2nd Update

The preferred way to do this is have grunt-usemin inject the PHP code during the build.  The recently released usemin 2.3.0 has this ability with blockReplacements.

feature request: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/337
commit: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/commit/83f6821a30020cbc9395d7257e0276cff142e219

Basically, you can't make grunt ignore PHP, but you can make it work with PHP.